# Is it possible to use a different material for geometry not in view of the camera?

Tags: materials, uv, camera, eevee-render-engine

[image: Here] Here I am using a UV Project Modifier to texture simple geometry from a camera, but the image stretches to adapt to the geometry that is behind the pillars, like this:
[image: stretching]Is it possible to use a different material for geometry that is not seen by the projection camera, without manually painting a clean plate?

Comment: If you are using Cycles please state so as a tag in your question.  Add  a materials tag please.

Comment: Geometry info node delivers information such a faces which have a normal that face away from Camera.  Backward Facing.  Dot product can give you the angle.  I do not understand your question completely.  I wonder if you can annotate something in the image .. such as ... I want the second material here.

Comment: Yeah sorry it's pretty confusing but I'm referring to the way the image stretches on the ground, behind the pillars, if there's any way to make that black. I guess I'd need raytracing so I don't think it's possible..

Comment: Perhaps you can use a combo of z location and normal information to get closer to what you want.

Comment: Render a depth map from your mapping-cam, then compare distance from that depth map with distance measured from actual geo (to the mapping cam).  If the real distance is greater than depth map distance, then its occluded.  This is the basis of how rasterizer shadows work.